# Websockets Disconnected when intermittant network drop or Network swtiched

Tags: websocket

We are using tomcat websocket implementation in our web application. Messages are pushed from server to client through websockets. Web socket messages are not pushed when intermittant connection drop or network is switch over but still web application is connected.

Let say for example i am connected to LAN and logged in app, now i connecting through wifi after wifi successfully connected i am disconnecting LAN with in fraction of second network is switched from LAN to wifi But after this messages are not pushed from server to client through websockets.

After network switch if i check the state of the websocket(readyState) which says 1 which means websocket connection is open but actually its not.

Can anyone faced this issue earlier and provide your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must create  a connection drop detection mechanism. The WebSocket protocol has ping/pong frames, but I don't know if Tomcat has that functionality. In some Webscoket frameworks you can define a timeout interval, and the server will ping the client regularly, if the client miss some pongs is disconnected.

If that functionality is not provided by Tomcat, you can still create your own. Just define a special type of message and repeat it to the server from the client. If you do not get any of those messages for a while, disconnect.